# Prove that there is no $a\in \mathbb R$ so that $f(x)= e^x(x^2+a) $ has only one extremum

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, maxima-minima

As to my understanding in order to calculate the behavior of the extrema of a function, a good approach is to examine the behavior of the first derivative of the given function.
So by calculating the derivative I got:
$$ f'(x)=(e^x(x^2+a))'=e^x(x^2+2x+a)$$

now in order to examine the behavior of $f(x)$ I examine where $f'(x)$ is positive or negative. And at the points where $f'(x)=0$ there will be an extremum.

So because $$ e^x >0 \space \forall x\in \mathbb R $$ whether $f'(x)$ is negative or positive is defined by the polynom $x^2 +2x+a$

Then by using the quadratic formula I found that for the discriminant $\Delta$ the following are true.

For $a<1$ it's $\Delta > 0 $ that means that for $a \in(-\infty,1)$, $f(x)$ has two extrema because the polynom has two roots and therefore the monotony of $f(x)$ changes twice.

And for $ a > 1$ it's $\Delta<0 $, the polynom has no real roots and therefore for $a\in(1,+\infty)$, $f(x)$ shows no change in its monotony and as a result it has $0$ extrema.

For the special case of $\Delta = 0$ the polynom is as well everywhere positive and therefore once again $f(x)$ has not extrema.

So there is no value for $a$ so that $f(x)$ will have only one extremum.

The thing is that just examining that way doesn't seem that "mathematically" correct to me and I wonder if there is any better way to examine and actually prove that there is no $a$ so that $f(x)$ has only one extremum.

Comment: This seems like a correct argument.

Comment: At a single extremum, $f$ would switch from strictly increasing to strictly decreasing or vice versa. So if there is a single extremum at $x_0$, $f$ must be strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,x_0)$ or on $(x,\infty)$. On the latter this is clearly not the case as $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. On $(-\infty,x_0)$, we have $f(x)\to 0$  as $x\to-\infty$, hence decreasing is possible only if $f(x)<0$ for $-\infty<x<x_0$. But for $x\ll 0$, clearly $f(x)>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've discussed correctly the cases for $a\ne 1$. The case for $a=1$ is not clearly examined. $\Delta=0$ means that the two solutions for the derivative are equal, both at $x=-1$. What you need to do is to show that this is not an extremum, even if the derivative is $0$, but an inflection point. You will need to take the second derivative, and check that it changes sign at $x=-1$. In a way, this problem is equivalent to showing that $x^3$ has no extremum, even if the derivative at $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Note that, since the discriminant is taken as zero in first derivative, second derivative will also have $x=-1$ as a root, whereas the third derivative is positive at $x=-1$ ; this only implies that second derivative has a minima.

Comment: @YourIDE You are correct. But $x=-1$ is not a double root of the second derivative, so the second derivative will change sign at that point.

Comment: I didn't say it was a double root. I said it is one of the roots.

Comment: I don't care that the second derivative has a minima. I could have a maxima, for all I care. What I care about is that the second derivative has a single root at $-1$, and the third derivative is not zero, therefore the second derivative changes sign.

Comment: @Andrei Thank you for your answer. I really liked the approach, even though I did not know about inflection points and their properties it gave me great insight after some reading.